# How to export SVG with preserveAspectRatio="none" in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I am manually adding `preserveAspectRatio="none` to SVGs exported from Adobe Illustrator in order to make them fill 100% of their container instead of maintaining aspect ratio.

Is there a way to have Illustrator automatically apply this property so I don't have to do it manually by hand every time?

Comment: No, but you can script this.

Comment: @joojaa I'd consider this to be "a way to do it". What would the script be, and where would we stick it?

Comment: Yeah thats fine but how do i teach you to script. After all nearly half of all things you dont know how to do have this answer. I mean sure i can write a script but you should learn to write your own.